# Merging Two Different Trees Issue - SVN

Tags: svn, merge

I performed SVN Merge using the option **Merging Two Different Trees** with trunk URL in 'FROM' and branch URL in the 'TO'. I had selected **Head Revision** in both and checked only one option, 'Ignore all white spaces'.

After the merge without any conflicts, many files were simply replaced in trunk with branch copy, even though trunk had changes.

Has anybody faced the same issue?

I believe this has got to do with revision number of a file. i.e. This happens if revision number of a file is greater in branch than in trunk. What would be a solution for this?

Comment: You merged _from_ trunk, but files in trunk were replaced?  That doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Patrick with this method of merging, 'from' and 'to' define which revisions are to be merged, not the target of the merge result. This is one way to reintegrate a branch into trunk. The merge result is going to be applied to the working copy - if that's pointing trunk then this all makes sense.

Comment: That makes sense now, but looking at [the docs](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-merge.html), that's expected behavior.  The section "Merge two different trees" describes exactly your situation, and says _"The net result is that trunk now looks exactly like the branch."_

Comment: Yes, this is correct behaviour

Comment: @Maden can you state what you are trying to achieve here? You are probably just using the wrong type of merge for what you want to do.

Comment: PatrickQuirk, Mounds - I wanted to copy changes in Branch to Trunk while retaining the changes in trunk. The branch was planned to be discarded.